# Посоветуйте бесплатную систему учета присутствия сотрудников или CRM какую

Tags: crm

Может кто посоветовать бесплатную систему учета присутствия сотрудников или CRM какую, что бы сотрудники просто могли отмечаться когда приходят и когда уходят. Жесткого контроля с просмотрами чем они там занимаются не нужно, просто минимальный функционал что бы потом посмотреть когда они отмечались.

Comment: Пост в ЖЖ с комментами от каждого.

Comment: google таблицы, возможно настроить под CRM